# JPA Table for Instanzvariable

Tags: jpa

I have this entity

```
@Entity
public class Measurement implements Serializable {
@ID
Long id;
double value;
String meter;
}
```

I would like to create an own table for each "Meter"(One per different value of the instanzvariable) . Is there Way to realise this with JAP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why even create a table for each object? Do you understand the meaning of relational databases and how to map an object?

What you need for this is a table "measurements" with columns id, value, meter.Each row will be a new set of values.

If you want to distinct "meters" then create a table "meter" , put values there and use foreign keys from table "measurements".

Maybe you should read something like this "http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/Relational_Database_Design.html"

Comment: i need to persists the measurements in seperate tables due to privacy. If i use Meter with with foreign keys from "measurement" it will rustlt in 1 Table with n-rows (meters) and another table with m-rows (measurements. What I want is:n-tables (meter) which contain the measurements. So that no one can see all measurements at the same time (if i set the permissions correctly)

Comment: what you want cannot be done the way you say. If you want to have permissions between users, you need create an intermediate table "users_measurements" and there you would specify which user has access to which measurement. Then display to the user only measurements that he has access to. You can create a table for each user.